# How to Applying operations like bold,italic,color etc on selected text of rich text?

Tags: flex4, flex4.6

I have a dragged object(like rectangle).when I double click on rectangle rich text will become visible and I can write text on rich text and applying operations like bold,color etc.After applying all operations and put mouse down on designArea(is a Group container) properties are not preserved.Only updated text in visible.

function foo(e:IndexChangeEvent):void{

```
                var styleObj:TextLayoutFormat=new TextLayoutFormat();
                styleObj.fontFamily=textcontrol.cb.selectedItem;
                textTarget.setFormatOfRange(styleObj);
                //textTarget.setStyle("fontFamily",textcontrol.cb.selectedItem);

            }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: It would be great to see your code. If you use RichText or RichTextEditor you can see simple text in the "text" property and formated one in the "htmlText" property. Do you use these properties?

Comment: no.How to format one in the "htmlText" property.pleaseprovide me the code.

Comment: It is not enough for me to understand the situation. I know it can be property of your firm. Could you post some pictures of the both processes (during editing and after it)? May be something more to let me understand the problem better.

Comment: how shoule i preserved the propertieslike bold itatic on selected text

Comment: I have applied all operations like bold,italic etc on selected text in textarea.Now I want to add this updated text on rich Text.Please help me its urjent.

Comment: Have a look at my example. Can it be helpful for you? http://it-skills.su/sosamples/webspark46/richtexteditor/

Comment: You have used RichTextEditor.I want to perform same operations in Rich Text.

Comment: You have written you have already implemented the styling in RichText. How have you achieved it? Can you save the text into a variable through TextConverter.export(...)?